# Where is Chapter XVI in Reed&Simon mathematical physics books?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

In the four-series volume "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics" by Reed and Simon, where is Chapter XVI?

In p. 280 of 4th book, in the introductory remark of *Chapter XIII.16 Schrödinger operators with periodic potentials*, the book says the following:

> One can in fact prove that $U(t)e^{-iHs}=e^{-iHs}U(t)(t)$ (Problem 135). A part of the analysis of $H$ is then a special case of general symmetry arguments which are the subject of **Chapter XVI**. In this sense our discussion here is premature. We emphasize to the reader that the constant fiber direct integrals described below are an example of a construction **Chapter XVI** (with most of the essential features) and that the fact that periodic Schrödinger operators have a direct integral decomposition is a direct consequence of (136). We remark that historically the essentials of the decomposition were discovered both by mathematicians (Floquet) and physicists (Bloch) who did not realize they were speaking group theory. We too shall not explicitly use the connection with the symmetry group here but will develop the theory directly.

But where is Chapter XVI? The end of volume 4 is *Chapter XIII. 17 An introduction to the spectral theory of non-self-adjoint operators*.

As an alternative question, it would be great for me if you suggest an another reference that deals on symmetry and decomposition of the Hilbert space.

Comment: Looking at reviews of this series I found on-line, it seems there were at least _five_ volumes projected.  It doesn't look like those were ever completed...

Comment: @boojum That is very interesting. I was unable to find volume 5. Could you give a relevant link that you found?

Comment: In the third paragraph of this review [ https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2005.11920273?journalCode=uamm20  ] , it tells a little of the history of the series.  Reed and Simon were planning a three-volume series, but when Volume II turned into II, III, and IV , they abandoned their plan beyond that (Vol. IV came out in 1978).  So there was apparently a brief interval when they were going to write at least five volumes, but gave  it up; the proposed Chapters were already numbered, however.  The last _published_ one is Chapter XIII in Volume 4.

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is in Simon's _Comprehensive Course in Analysis_, part 4 (2015), but someone else would know a good reference for you better than I would...